# How do those running a US caucus vote?

Tags: caucus

This might seem like a stupid question. Say you're a precinct chair or a volunteer.  Can you vote in the caucus you're helping conduct?

Seems like some volunteers... like door captains have duties to attend to while the caucus is going on (make sure nobody enters after the deadline)...  so they can't actually participate. Can they vote in the caucus? How would this work?

Comment: I don't see why not. They won't be on duty for the entire time the polls are open. Why would you think they can't?

Comment: It doesn't work like a poll right... where you can just cast your vote and go away... At least in Iowa, everyone has to be gathered together during the headcounts... then there's electing the delegates. So it's a whole process where you're gathered together.